Cannot uninstall mysql-server-8.0_8.0.39-0ubuntu0.24.04.2_amd.deb in 24.04-01 LTS due to broken unit file
I'm in the process of upgrading form 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS.
After re-enabling other sources, my HAM-Logboog "CQRLOG" replaced mariadb-server upon installation by mysql-server. It's something I found strange, but I went with it.
However, mysql-server did seemingly not install correctly and I now can get it neither to work, nor uninstall it again. If e.g I do a...
apt-get --purge autoremove "^mysql.*"

I get (among others):
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
Failed to start mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not found.
Unit mysql.service could not be found.

I'd like to either (a) fix the mysql-server-8.0 or (b) purge it completely and revert to mariadb again.
Do you have any ideas about how I can handle this seemingly broken package properly?

... all it needed was a
dpkg --force-all --purge mysql-server-8.0

... so this was an easy one
